# Hoarding food in mouth

Tags: toddler, eating

My 2.5-year-old has started hoarding food in her mouth, and won't chew, until her mouth is just full of food. Most of the time it seems like it's because she's distracted with something or doesn't especially feel like eating something (right now, the only things she really likes are her M&M's and mac and cheese).

Anyone else faced this? What did you do to get around it? I'm assuming it's just a phase - should I just wait it out?

Comment: I'm still trying to figure this one out with my 15mo old.

Answer (score 3):

My 2 and half daughter did, and sometimes still does, the same thing. I just ask/tell her to "chew chew chew".  Thank goodness she hasn't hurt herself.  I just keep an eye out is all.